# Looping try/catch statement

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm trying to take two random rowid from my database. Everything works but I have a scenario when there is only one rowid. I want to make a loop on my try/catch until there is second number in my database.
What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

```java
public void Kaslaimejo() {
    String sql = "SELECT rowid FROM Zaidejai WHERE Pirmas < 4 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 2";
    Integer value1 = null, value2 = null; 
    Integer judesiukas1 = null, judesiukas2 = null;

    int a = 0;
    int k = 15; // kiek kartu? Reikia infinity padaryti

    for (a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
        try {
            Connection conn = Serveris.connect();
            Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    value1 = rs.getInt("rowid");
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        value2 = rs.getInt("rowid");
                        PreparedStatement buvo = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Zaidejai SET Numeriukas = ? WHERE rowid = ?");
                        buvo.setInt(1, i);
                        buvo.setInt(2, value1);
                        int buvolala = buvo.executeUpdate  ();
                        PreparedStatement buvo2 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Zaidejai SET Numeriukas = ? WHERE rowid = ?");
                        buvo2.setInt(1, i);
                        buvo2.setInt(2, value2);
                        int buvolala2 = buvo2.executeUpdate  ();// 
                        i++;
                    }
                System.out.println("Pirmas zaidejas" + value1); // atspausdina 1 random zaideja is duomenu bazes
                System.out.println("Antras zaidejas" + value2); // atspausdina 2 random zaideja is duomenu bazes
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            a--;
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Right now my program loops two times and then gives me `SQLException`. How I can loop my program until there is no `SQLException`?

Comment: What is the exact SQLException that you are receiving? Its type and its message?

Comment: I'm receiving error SQLException message that there is no secong number in the table. Im reveiving null.

Comment: But you're ignoring the exception in the code you've provided. And next does not throw an Exception when no data is available. It returns false.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited my post. I left some code behind. I'm trying to understand. How i'm ignoring exception? If no data is available code cannot get two random numbers and exception pops up.

Comment: In the catch block, do e.printStackTrace(); What exactly appears then?

Comment: It gives me this: Pirmas zaidejas1
Antras zaidejasnull
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Serveris.Kaslaimejo(Serveris.java:79)
 at Serveris.main(Serveris.java:169)                                                                                 By the way, really thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. First, you need to check what is at line 79 of your code. You are trying to access something that is null. It is probably ``value2``, since there is no second row. Is something missing from the code you have posted? Also, try out the answer by Olivier. It is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I'm trying to access second number but there is no second number, so loop should go around and around until someone insert second number.  Line 79 shows value2 (null). I posted all my code to codeshare. Sorry, it is a mess, i'm trying to learn. https://codeshare.io/anlxpM

Comment: Don't worry about any mess. That's the way to learn. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The logic becomes easier if you add the values to a list

```
var values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (values.Count < 2) {
    try (Connection conn = Serveris.connect();
         Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql))
    {
        while (values.Count < 2 && rs.next()) {
            Integer v = rs.getInt("rowid");
            values.Add(v);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
}
//TODO: process the values here
```

The advantage is, that you can retrieve one value at the first database query and the second at a later one or both in the same round and you don't have to keep track of which one of two variables to use.

(Bear with me with the syntax details, I'm not a Java programmer.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've tried to write what I think you're trying to do.
You wait for ever until someone puts at least two entries in the database.
You extract two values, process them, then wait some more.

Some points to watch out:
1. Object comparisons need to be made with `.equals()` not with `==`
2. You might want to provide some way to break out of the infinite loop I've written (`while(true)`).
3. Careful with `null` values. They might produce `NullPointerException`.
4. Try to break up your code into methods. Each large block of code could go into each own method.

```
public void Kaslaimejo(){
    String sql = "SELECT rowid FROM Zaidejai WHERE Pirmas < 4 ORDER BY random() LIMIT 2";
    Integer judesiukas1 = null, judesiukas2 = null;


    while(true) {

        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

        while (values.size() < 2) {
            try (Connection conn = Serveris.connect();
                 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
                if( rs.next() ){
                    Integer value = rs.getInt("rowid");
                    values.add(value);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try( Connection conn = Serveris.connect()) {
            PreparedStatement buvo = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Zaidejai SET Numeriukas = ? WHERE rowid = ?");
            buvo.setInt(1, i);
            buvo.setInt(2, values.get(0));
            int buvolala = buvo.executeUpdate  ();
            PreparedStatement buvo2 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Zaidejai SET Numeriukas = ? WHERE rowid = ?");
            buvo2.setInt(1, i);
            buvo2.setInt(2, values.get(1));
            int buvolala2 = buvo2.executeUpdate  ();//
            i++;
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection conn = Serveris.connect();

        try {
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Pirmas FROM Zaidejai WHERE rowid = ?");
            PreparedStatement pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Pirmas FROM Zaidejai WHERE rowid = ?");
            pstmt.setInt(1, values.get(0));
            pstmt2.setInt(1, values.get(1));
            ResultSet myrsv = pstmt.executeQuery();
            ResultSet myrsv2 = pstmt2.executeQuery();


            {

                if (myrsv.next()) {
                    judesiukas1 = myrsv.getInt("Pirmas");
                    if (myrsv2.next()) {
                        judesiukas2 = myrsv2.getInt("Pirmas");
                    }

                }
                //System.out.println("Pirmo zaidejo veiksmas" + myrsv.getInt("Pirmas"));
                //System.out.println("Antro zaidejo veiksmas" + myrsv2.getInt("Pirmas"));

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if (judesiukas1.equals(judesiukas2)) // careful here. NullPointerException may happen.
        {
            try {
                PreparedStatement laim = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Zaidejai SET Rezultatas = ? WHERE rowid = ?"); // ble ble update reikia naudoti , o ne insert into. Insert kai sukuriame nauja kazka tik
                PreparedStatement laim2 = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Zaidejai SET Rezultatas = ? WHERE rowid = ?");
                laim.setString(1, "Lygiosios");
                laim.setInt(2, values.get(0));
                laim2.setString(1, "Lygiosios");
                laim2.setInt(2, values.get(1));
                int irasyk = laim.executeUpdate  (); // kodel executeupdate, o ne executequery????
                int irasyk2 = laim2.executeUpdate  (); // kodel executeupdate, o ne executequery????
                {


                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print("Lygiosios");
        } else {

            //  (1) - Rock
            //  (2)  Scissors
            //  (3) - Paper
            switch (values.get(0)){
                case 1:
                    if (judesiukas2 == 2)
                        System.out.print("Zaidejas 1 wins!");

                    else
                        System.out.print("Zaidejas 2 wins!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (judesiukas2 == 3)
                        System.out.print("Zaidejas 1 wins!");
                    else
                        System.out.print("Zaidejas 2 wins!");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (judesiukas2 == 1)
                        System.out.print("Zaidejas 1 wins!");
                    else
                        System.out.print("Zaidejas 2 wins!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How i can loop my program until there is no SQLException?

Change this (because, it will only allow to loop two times)

```
for (a = 0; a < 2; a++) {
```

to

```
while(true)
```

Put everything inside `while(true)`, if exception occurred, then it will come out from the while loop. Something similar :

```
try
{
  while(true)
  {
  ...
  ...
  }
  ...
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    // do somthing
}
```

Comment: But is it possible to do this with for loop? I did a < 1;. It does one loop but if there is catch it does a--; so it should loop again. I dont know why its not working. :/